# Have a PHP redirect to login page, not forcing login

Tags: php, html, security, session, authentication

I created a small php site for gameserver management, but it is not forcing unlogged in users to login. I have added a redirect if a session is not active, and have destroyed the sessions on logout. The site is here http://zelware.co.uk/gameman

It forces you to login the first time but if you take login.php off of the URL it allows you into the main area again. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Without some of your code or what you have tried (code-specific), we'll hardly be able to help you.

Comment: it probably would help for debugging if you had the session+redirect code

Comment: Check for the session on EVERY page then, and show some code of what you tried relating to that, cause you probably messed up somewhere.

Comment: Though I tried your url and I'm apparently automatically logged in, cannot log out. Something's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need a if statement with

```
$_SESSION['loggedin']==TRUE;
```

to check if someone is logged in or not.
Also consider to set session_id() and redirect with this, too.

Comment: That is SO BAD, Everyone can create a session with tools, so just a loggedin = true is the most unsafe way to authenticate a login....

Comment: No! That's a misunderstanding. I didn't said just the above.

Answer (score 0):

to authenticate users, you need a simple mechanism:

- all pages should be protected by a check which looks for some session value, and redirect to login page if this value is not exists. you can write the code of this check in a separate function/file and call/include it in every page of your site.

  ```
  is_user_logged_in(){
      return $_SESSION['logged_in']; // it is a boolean value, which should be set TRUE by the login function
  }

  //in every page of yours you should call this
  if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
      //redirect to you login page
      header("Location: http://yoursitename.com/login_page.php");
  }
  ```
- login page should validate the username/password, and if valid, create the session value you are checking for in every other page.

  ```
  if ( valid_user($username, $password) ){
      // this is the value you should check for in other pages
      $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
      // you may also need to store other user-related info in the session
      $_SESSION['user'] = array("id" => 1 , "username" => "test_user") // a data array from DB
  }
  ```
- logout page should destroy the session value you are checking for in every other page.

  ```
  unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
  session_destroy();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a mechanism for verifying if the user is logged in. 
When logging in, the system sets a session cookie - a random, unique hash. The hash is stored as a cookie, and in the database, along with the username, password, IP and time of the login.

When the user visits the page, you call a function that looks somewhat like this: (not exactly, this isn't really that good, just basic checking, you should also check if the IP matches and if the session has expired)

```
  function verify_login() {
 //
 $hash = $_COOKIE['loginhash'];
    if($hash != ''):
        $hash = mysql_real_escape_string($hash);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE hash = '$hash'";


    else:
        header('Location: login.php');
    endif;



    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                                    echo 'The user is logged in.';


    }
    else:
        header('Location: login.php');
    endif;

      }
```